# Azure: Add existing Virtual Machines to new Application Gateway in same region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

We already have created two virtual machines in the North Europe region.
Now, I want to add these two machines in Application Gateway, but as per Azure documents while creating an Application gateway one cannot use a virtual network with existing VMs in it. 
Is there a way around to create an Application gateway in the same network as VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Application Gateway and the VM in the same VNET.

VNET can have multiple subnets. When you deploy Application Gateway, you need to specify a Subnet and you are not supposed to deploy VMs in the same subnet where Application Gateway resides.

So create a new subent and place your VM or if the VMs already exists, you create a new subnet for your Application Gateway.